# Format floating point value to 3 decimal digits in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function (seconds and milliseconds are passed) that can return a string with this format -> `"1,001"`(or instead of the comma a point if you are american).

In addition there only should be 3 decimals after the comma. If you just add a comma in between it wouldn't work definitely...

So my question is, if there is a method or any trick to do this.

Note: I'm new to JS

Comment: so for example, would 1403 ms return 1,403? And 5 seconds 23ms would return 5,023?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does that fit your requirement?

```
function format(seconds, milliseconds) {
    return (seconds + milliseconds / 1000).toFixed(3);
}

format(1, 1); // 1.001
format(5, 23); // 5.023
```

Comment: ohh god yes that was what I was looking for. Thx. Sometimes I think in unusual ways....